# How to expand your x axis of datetimeIndex with matplotlib Python

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have two `dataframes`. I understand the time frame of the two are not exactly equal. one is an effect of the corona versus my operations. and the effect began to show after the outbreak.

Below is the `snippet` of my code:

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = covid19_df[covid19_df.countriesAndTerritories == "Germany"]["cases"].plot(label="Reported Cases")
ax1 = covid19_df[covid19_df.countriesAndTerritories == "Germany"]["deaths"].plot(label="Deaths")
df["NO OF CAPTURED FARMERS"].plot(label= "Number of farmers")
plt.ylabel("Number of cases", fontsize=15, labelpad=20)
plt.xlabel("Dates", fontsize=15, labelpad=20)
plt.legend()
sns.despine()
```

Here is the current plot:

[image]

I don't know why the blue line does not show

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlim.html.

ax.set_xlim(your beginning date time , your ending date time)